# Can Time Machine backup other partitions on the same drive?

Tags: mac, partitioning, time-machine

I have a Mac Mini, but would like to use an external drive to store data. I would also like to have everything backed up.

If I had a single external drive, and partitioned it into Storage and Backup drives, will Time Machine be able to back up both the internal Mac Mini HD, AND the Storage partition on the external drive's Backup partition?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can, so long as it's the right format, it will even add it automatically to the backup list…
… but what's the point?

Backing up to the same drive is terrible disaster-prevention.

Comment: Thanks for this, I totally get your point. So ultimately, two external hard drives would be needed, one for each purpose (storage and backup).

Comment: Indeed. There's an adage, "Any data stored in fewer than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary". By that, you should also have another backup off-site, in case the house burns down.